# partition scheme and boot sequence for triple boot: mac, bodhi, *buntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu, uefi

To install Lubuntu I can shrink `sda5`, Bodhi Linux, and create a partition before?

from `fdisk`:

```
device      size        type
/dev/sda1   200M        EFI system
/dev/sda2   93.1G       Apple HFS/HFS+      
/dev/sda3   619M        Apple boot
/dev/sda4   1M          BIOS boot
/dev/sda5   137G        Linux Filesystem
/dev/sda6   2G          Linux swap
```

The problem is that Bodhi, on sda5, uses sda6 for swap.

Or, does that not make sense here?  Looking for rational and pragmatic partition scheme to add Lubuntu and, maybe, Xubuntu to [this Mac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446093/17056).

Can I delete `sda6`, shrink `sda5`, create a new ext4 partition after `sda5` for *buntu, then a swap after that?  For something like:

```
device      size        type
/dev/sda1   200M        EFI system
/dev/sda2   93.1G       Apple HFS/HFS+      
/dev/sda3   619M        Apple boot
/dev/sda4   1M          BIOS boot
/dev/sda5   75G         Linux Filesystem
/dev/sda6   75G         Linux Filesystem
/dev/sda7   2G          Linux swap
```

with Bodhi on `sda5` and *buntu on `sda6?  This would be reasonable?

(Bodhi was installed with a mount point of `/`.  The *buntu partition should, similarly, have a mount point of `/` and still work with `rEFInd`?)

**Does it make much difference whether or how *buntu is installed:  EFI or BIOS?**  Bodhi was inadvertently installed in BIOS mode.

Comment: Ubuntu, or in fact [almost any] GNU/Linux will use swap wherever it is located; so it can be moved or left where it is. At worst you may need to alter /etc/fstab to reflect change (if UUID, or /sda? changes)..

Comment: Can I delete the swap partition, shrink Bodhi, add Lubuntu partition, then add swap at the end?

Comment: It's what I'd :)   When you re-create it, it'll have a new UUID (unique identifier) so this will be the change you need to make to `/etc/fstab`. This is easy, and shouldn't stop a boot (just error messages, a little slower boot & swap may be disabled until corrected)

Comment: You are showing both an ESP as sda1 for UEFI boot and a bios_grub partition sda4 for BIOS boot. With Mac you only want UEFI boot. Did you install Bodhi or Ubuntu in BIOS mode? How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. And Macs were EFI even before Windows changed to UEFI 5 years ago. EFI is earlier version of UEFI and Macs have updated to somewhat inbetween early EFI and newer UEFI, but not fully converted yet.

Comment: @oldfred Probably Bodhi was installed in BIOS mode.  This is an older Mac running EFI and not UEFI.